# How to count from a looped range

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

So here is a bit of the code that retrieves data from a list where dates may or may not be inputted. If there is a date, the month will be extracted, and based on what month it is, I want the cell (17,4 in this case) to count how many dates of that month. The loop goes through the page to pull out all the dates but I do not know how to count or add more than one to (17,4).

```
for(var i =8;i<=j;i++) {
    var dates = oppwon.getRange(i,22).getValue();
    var tiers = oppwon.getRange(i,14).getValue();


  var month = new Date(dates).getMonth();



  switch (true){
      case((month==1)):
          if(tiers==1)
    {summary.getRange(17,4).setValue()+1;}

        break;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- You want to count up the value of the cell of "D17" (`getRange(17,4)`) when `month == 1` and `tiers == 1`.

If my understanding is correct, how about this modification? Please think of this as just one of several answers

#### Modified script:

Please modify your script as follows.

From:

```
for(var i =8;i<=j;i++) {
    var dates = oppwon.getRange(i,22).getValue();
    var tiers = oppwon.getRange(i,14).getValue();


  var month = new Date(dates).getMonth();



  switch (true){
      case((month==1)):
          if(tiers==1)
    {summary.getRange(17,4).setValue()+1;}

        break;
```

To:

```
var range = summary.getRange(17,4);  // Added
var currentValue = range.getValue();  // Added
for (var i = 8; i <= j; i++) {
  var dates = oppwon.getRange(i,22).getValue();
  var tiers = oppwon.getRange(i,14).getValue();
  var month = new Date(dates).getMonth();
  switch (true) {
    case (month == 1):
    if (tiers == 1) {
      range.setValue(++currentValue);  // Modified
    }
    break;
```

- At first, the current value from the cell of "D17" is retrieved. Then, new value is put to the cell by adding the number of `1`.

#### Note:

- To use `getValue()` in the for loop leads to the high process cost. But I'm not sure about your whole script. So I couldn't propose about this.

#### References:

- [getValue()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getvalue)
- [setValue(value)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setvaluevalue)

If I misunderstood your question and this was not the result you want, I apologize. At that time, can you provide the sample Spreadsheet and your script for replicating your issue. By this, I would like to confirm it.

Comment: Yes! Thank you this works great, sorry I didnt know how to clearly explain what I wanted but you got it.

Comment: @apfick Thank you for replying. No problem. I'm glad your issue was resolved. Thank you, too.